# Java Minesweeper - ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java, minesweeper

I am new to Java programming and would like to seek your help.
I'm trying to develop a simple minesweeper game using Java. However, I keep getting the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at practice.week.pkg4.PracticeWeek4.main(PracticeWeek4.java:55)"

This occurs when I'm trying to place digits around the square which has a bomb. I understand that perhaps the 1 has went out of the array, causing the exception to occur. However, I'm not sure how to go about catching the error. Would appreciate any kind help.

Eg: Sample Output

1 1 1

1 B 1

1 1 1

Here is my code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int rows = 9;
        int cols = 9;
        char[][] map = new char[rows][cols];
        int count = 0;


        for(int i = 0; i<map.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<map[i].length; j++)
            {
                map[i][j] = '.';
            }
        }

        Random rnd = new Random();
        do
        {
            int x = rnd.nextInt(rows);
            int y = rnd.nextInt(cols);

            for(int i = 0; i<map.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<map[i].length; j++)
                {


if(map[x][y] != 'B' && x > 0 & y > 0)
                { 
                    map[x][y] = 'B';
                    map[x-1][y-1] = '1'; 
                    map[x-1][y] = '1';
                    map[x-1][y+1] = '1';
                    map[x][y-1] = '1';
                    map[x][y+1] = '1';
                    map[x+1][y-1] = '1';
                    map[x+1][y] = '1';
                    map[x+1][y+1] = '1';
                    count++; 
                }

                }   

            }
        }
        while(count < 10);


        for(int x = 0; x<map.length; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y <map[x].length; y++)
            {

            }
        }

        for(int x = 0; x<map.length; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y<map[x].length; y++)
            {
                System.out.print(map[x][y] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }



    }
```

Comment: x and y might be zero, thus, when subtracting 1 it could be -1 which is not a valid index causing the error

Comment: There is no negative index -1 : map[0-1][0-1] = '1' ==> map[-1][-1] = '1'

Comment: How do i go about rectifying it? @AndrewL

Comment: Add an if statement that checks if x or y are 0. For example: if(x > 0 && y > 0){ map[x-1][y-1]='1'; }

Comment: Thank u all! it works fine now. I just have another qn. What if i want the 1 to become a 2 or 3? how can i go about doing it then? This is based on the number of bombs around the square similarly.

Comment: @AndrewL What Abdelhak said makes perfect sense. He is saying, at index 0, the code will attempt to do "map[-1][-1] = '1'" which is not valid.

Comment: @Arman Ahh, I read it differently, thought he meant differently :)

Comment: I edited my code but errors still occurs.

Comment: That's because you also have to check the upper bound. Because map[map.length][map.length] is nonexistant. So change your if statement to "if(x > 0 && y > 0 && x < map.length && y < map[i].length)

Comment: @Arman what do u mean by the upper bound?

Comment: @user1971823 Arrays have a lower bound, the first index which is 0, and an upper bound, the last index of the array. So if "i" in the for loop is equal to the upper bound of the array, then checking "i+1" will cause an error, since the index i+1 does not exist.

Comment: You have to place the bombs in the map array first, then go through the map array and calculate the numbers.  Two separate processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The do-while loop for setting the mines is on the right track, but the way you are updating the counts for surrounding blocks is causing the IndexOutOfBoundsException. And these two loops

```
for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++)
```

serve no purpose. You need to rearrange it to handle multiple mines, etc, so why not set all the mines first:

```
do
{
    int x = rnd.nextInt(rows);
    int y = rnd.nextInt(cols);
    if (map[x][y] != 'B')
    {
        map[x][y] = 'B';
        count++;
    }
} while(count < 10);
```

Then go through the map, and count the number of mines surrounding each block:

```
for (int x = 0; x < map.length; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < map[x].length; y++)
    {
        if (map[x][y] == 'B')
            continue;

        // Count the number of mines around map[x][y]
        int mines = 0;
        for (int xOffset = -1; xOffset <= 1; xOffset++)
        {
            // This is an important step - without it, we will access elements off the edge of the map
            if (x + xOffset < 0 || x + xOffset >= map.length)
                continue;

            for (int yOffset = -1; yOffset <= 1; yOffset++)
            {
                // Another check for the edge of the map
                if (y + yOffset < 0 || y + yOffset >= map[x].length)
                    continue;

                if (map[x + xOffset][y + yOffset] == 'B')
                    mines++;
            }
        }

        map[x][y] = "012345678".charAt(mines); // Get the number as a character
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, i don't get what the last line does! can you explain to me?

Comment: It converts a number into its' character equivalent. So if you have the number `6`, and you get the character at that index, it will be '6'. And it puts that number into the map. You may want to use a space instead of '0' though...

Comment: I changed it to a ',' instead. Can you also explain about the offset for loops and if? the code works but i don't really understand it.

Comment: The offsets go between -1 and +1. So when you add that range to [x, y], you get a 3X3 grid of all the pixels around [x,y]. If the X offset means that we go off the edge of the map, then we skip that offset. Same goes for the Y offset.

Comment: So its like a subarray of our main array?

Comment: Exactly! It's the same as writing out each of the 8 cases by hand, which you did in your updated post, but it only needs two 'if' statements to make sure everything is within the boundaries of the map, as opposed to 8.

Comment: I have a better understanding now. However, can i ask why our offset value is from -1 - 1? Can't it be from 0-2?

Comment: If you have a point [x,y], then to the left is [x - 1, y], and to the right is [x + 1, y]. Up is [x, y - 1], down is [x, y + 1]. You _could_ use 0 - 2, but you would have to subtract 1 from it everywhere you use it, like this: `map[x + xOffset - 1][y + yOffset - 1]`, so it's much easier to use the range [-1,+1] to begin with.